# VB.NET NHibernate Configuration

Tags: database, vb.net, nhibernate, orm

I can't seem to find any decent (and recent) NHibernator examples for VB.NET on Visual Basic 2010 Express. However I have been trying to piece together everything I can.

However I **always** seem to get this error.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.Cfg.HibernateConfigException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.Cfg.HibernateConfigException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
a: An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer.
```

I have `nhibernator.cfg.xml` at the root of the project containing the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">

  <!-- For simplicity, the NHibernate configuration is stored in this file.
  It must be named hibernate.cfg.xml and marked in Visual Studio to be copied
  to the output folder.  -->

  <session-factory>

    <!-- By default NHibernate is aggressive in closing connections between
    SQL statments.  This unfortunately causes a problem when reading ID
    numbers assigned by Access (e.g. in AutoNumber fields).  See comments
    in the Test 1 section of Program.cs. -->

    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>

    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.JetDriver.JetDialect, NHibernate.JetDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.JetDriver.JetDriver, NHibernate.JetDriver</property>

    <!-- The Sample.mdb file is located in the folder containing the
    solution file.  This is three folders upward.  Relative paths
    are supported in Jet connection strings.  -->

    <property name="connection.connection_string">Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=database.accdb</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any help and insight is appreciated.

Comment: i just removed `hibernate.connection.release_mode` property as it was invalid according to the `xsd` sheets. still same error.

Comment: What is inside your app.config or web.config file? You can control where the hibernate configuration file is read from by using settings in the initial configuration file or place the entire configuration inside app.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have nhibernator.cfg.xml at the root of the project containing the following

I think you want to name it `hibernate.cfg.xml` by default. Otherwise point the configuration to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file set to copy to the output folder? It's in its properties in Visual Studio. You should set it to copy always.